# Android,How to load gif in curlpager in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-glide

```
PageCurlView pageCurlView = (PageCurlView) findViewById(R.id.curlView);

List<Integer> pages_id = new ArrayList<>();
pages_id.add(R.drawable.page1);
pages_id.add(R.drawable.splash_gif);
pages_id.add(R.raw.splash_gif);
pages_id.add(R.drawable.ic_action_doll);

pageCurlView.setCurlView(pages_id);
```

> Libary:
>
> compile 'app.num.numandroidpagecurleffect:numandroidpagecurleffect:1.0'

Comment: Provide to xml file and which library you can use

Comment: <app.num.numandroidpagecurleffect.PageCurlView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/curlView"/>

Comment: Libary: compile 'app.num.numandroidpagecurleffect:numandroidpagecurleffect:1.0'

Comment: I got the curlView,and loading the images in curlview...but i didnt get the gif format in that curlview.how should i get the gif format in that view

Comment: Also using Glide and load any gif from your projects

Comment: if i use glide libary for separate image view is supporting the gif,but now im using curlview to load image,so glide didnt support curlview,glide only support imageview....

Comment: Try any gif supported library and try to make object at runtime. Like: `pages_id.add(new GifSupportedObj.setPath(R.drawable.your_gif));`